# Replaced the wax ring but now it bubbles when the shower runs

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I replaced the wax ring after it started leaking now when the shower is running the toilet bubbles and if you push the toilet you can hear air escaping from around the toilet bolts plunging doesn't help it will slowly drain then you're able to flush the toilet properly

Comment: take a look at the link in my answer it will probably describe a similar scenario of leaking around the ring. However please note you might have a partial clog just after the joint where shower drain meets toilet drain. You might want to snake that.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have a drain vent problem on the drain to which both the shower and toilet connect.  It could be anything from a clogged vent (most likely if the system was working for a long time and then suddenly started leaking from the toilet flange) to an incorrectly designed stack.

If you want to tackle the problem yourself, you need to understand how vents allow traps and siphons to function properly in a [DWV system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain-waste-vent_system).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a clogged toilet - where the water backs up and the wax ring can't endure the pressure of that water and starts leaking. Your flange could be broken and so you do not have a good seal. Your toilet flange could be too high or too low.

Your vent could be clogged but it is also possible the shower drain is partially clogged just past where your toilet drain is met, the back pressure will force the water towards the toilet where you have a either poor seal or the back pressure against that wax ring is too high and therefore it leaks.

You can look at this [link here](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/how-to/how-to-repair-cast-iron-toilet-flange) for some information.